# Eclipselink optimal cache settings suitable for cache co-ordination. UPDATE: causing deadlocks while using SEND_NEW_OBJECTS_WITH_CHANGES

Tags: jpa, caching, jms, eclipselink

My tech stack

> EclipseLink 2.6.3, JPA 2.0, IBM Websphere 8.5.5.8 and JTA enabled

Currently in my project I have enabled SHARED_CACHE mode and have below cache settings on all my non read only entities and CacheType is **SOFT_WEAK**

```
@Cacheable
@Cache(
        alwaysRefresh=true,
        refreshOnlyIfNewer=true,
        coordinationType=CacheCoordinationType.SEND_NEW_OBJECTS_WITH_CHANGES,
        expiry=3600000 //changed according to entity
        )
```

I have also configured JMS cache coordination as my app is hosted on clustered environment.

My question is are my cache settings are inline with EclipseLink best practices in accordance with cache coordination in place?

Should I need to change anything apart from what mentioned above ?

**UPDATE:**

Now I have an issue with this cache coordination  settings i.e CacheCoordinationType.SEND_NEW_OBJECTS_WITH_CHANGES,it enters into deadlock mode and ends up locking threads and my server crashes.Not sure what's happening here. I've debugged source code and it shows it acquires locks on thread & cache of the object to merge the changes but that should be happening in minimal time.Why is it taking 10mins for the locks to release?

Any help would be appreciated.

Below is the error I'm facing in my QA/Prod env.

```
    [14/09/17 13:37:16:015 BST] 000003d4 SystemOut     O [EL Finer]: 2017-09-14 13:37:16.014--ServerSession(772764452)--Thread(Thread[SIBJMSRAThreadPool : 7,5,main])--


Potential deadlock encountered while thread: SIBJMSRAThreadPool : 7 attempted to lock object of class: class com.jlr.vista.business.order.model.event.StatusUpdateEvent with id: 324,836,575, entering deadlock avoidance algorithm.  This is a notice only.
[14/09/17 13:47:16:015 BST] 000003d4 SystemOut     O [EL Severe]: 2017-09-14 13:47:16.015--ServerSession(772764452)--Thread(Thread[SIBJMSRAThreadPool : 7,5,main])--MAX TIME 600 seconds EXCEEDED FOR WRITELOCKMANAGER WAIT.  Waiting on Entity type: com.business.model.event.UpdateEvent with pk: 324,836,575 currently locked by thread: SIBJMSRAThreadPool : 1 with the following trace:
                atsun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
                atjava.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:237)
                atjava.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2187)
                atcom.ibm.ws.util.BoundedBuffer$GetQueueLock.await(BoundedBuffer.java:286)
                atcom.ibm.ws.util.BoundedBuffer.waitGet_(BoundedBuffer.java:425)
                atcom.ibm.ws.util.BoundedBuffer.take(BoundedBuffer.java:823)
                atcom.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool.getTask(ThreadPool.java:1059)
                atcom.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1916)
 (There is no English translation for this message.)
```

NOTE: My application is very large and have almost 150+ entities which are writable.

Comment: Yes, you should need to change them as they completely depend on your application usage patterns. Entities with higher read to write usage patterns need different settings, the cache usage is affected by memory constraints, so there is no point sending updates for entities that aren't in the cache etc.  Also note that SEND_NEW_OBJECTS_WITH_CHANGES can be expensive, and its value depends on weighing the cost of sending the objects to fill in references vs reading them from the DB if/when needed

Comment: I don't understand what other option should I use ? I'm using SEND_NEW_OBJECTS_WITH_CHANGES  to avoid stale data and reduce optimistic locks in my cluster environment. So what else should I go for ?

Comment: Depends, which is why I brought it up. New objects are really only needed to fix the references to any existing objects already in the cache, bringing them up to date without re-reading them, so you should look at their usage and how often this occurs.  Generally invalidation is recommended as there is an overhead to sending changes around and merging them into remote caches, but it depends on cache hits/misses of these changesets and the number of writes to reads.